# Django FloatField with amount of decimals as stored in database

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

Consider the following example model:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    weight = FloatField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

The `FloatField` will be a field of type `double` in MySQL. Now I want to be able to use a variable amount of decimals for this field. So when I save a Product with weight `50`, it must be stored as `50` in the database. When the weight is `50.0`, it must be stored as `50.0`. This seems default behaviour, so the weights are stored in the database like how they were originally saved.

However, when retrieving a product from the database, an original weight of `50` is converted to `50.0`, so a decimal is added. That is probably because of the fact that the retrieved value will be converted to a `float` in Django, which automatically adds the decimal. To overcome that problem, I tried to extend the `from_db_value` method of the `FloatField`, hoping the be able to fetch the original value (`50` instead of `50.0`). But at that point the value is already converted to `50.0`:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    weight = DynamicDecimalFloatField(db_index=True, null=True, blank=True)

class DynamicDecimalFloatField(models.FloatField):
    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        print(value) # prints 50.0

        return value
```

What would be the best way to access the original value from the database? Then I would be able to make my own method to check the amount of decimals and return the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve original value without decimal value of `0`, you can use `'{0:g}'.format(float(value))`.

Comment: Great, that works. Do I have to extend the original FloatField as suggested in my question or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: yes, you can user original FloatField and also you can user `floatformat` to display float value without decimal.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/builtins/#floatformat